# Closure in discrete, indiscrete, cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology

Let S be a subset of a set X. Describe the closure of S when

- (1) X has the discrete topology,
- (2) X has the indiscrete topology and
- (3) X has the cofinite topology.

How to prove that problem???
Please, help me....

Comment: Do you know the definition of closure? What is a closed set containing $S$ in these three topologies?

Answer (score 2):

Some hints, keeping in mind that the closure of $S$ is the smallest closed set that contains $S$:

(1) Every set is closed in the discrete topology (because every set is open).

(2) Distinguish between $S = \emptyset$ and $ \neq \emptyset$. What are the closed sets in the indiscrete topology?

(3) Distinguish between finite $S$ and infinite $S$. What are all the closed sets of $X$?